# [OneSignal][Unity] Create ID after login

Tags: push-notification, onesignal, unity-game-engine

I am running into a small issue in my unity app after adding the OneSignal plugin. I can receive push notifications if I send them from the web server and everything is fast. However, my concern is that OneSignal assigns one ID to the device not to the user.

My question is: there is any way to create an ID after my login?

The only problem in the actual state is if the user has multiple accounts or if a friend connects from that device. Both users would have the same ID and therefore both would receive the same notifications.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [OneSignal.SendTag](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/onesignal-unity-sdk-api#SendTag) in your app to tag the user with your userId when they login. Then when they logout call [OneSiganl.DeleteTag](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/onesignal-unity-sdk-api#DeleteTag) to remove it.

This will allow you to send a notification with the `tags` field on the OneSignal [create notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-create-notification) REST API POST call.